# ios: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'LOTAnimationView'

Tags: ios, animation, lottie

I keep getting this error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'LOTAnimationView'
on the  **if let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "pop_heart") {** line of code. I think the format of the code may be wrong. Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Thanks :)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("view loaded")

    if let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "pop_heart") {
        animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)
        animationView.center = self.view.center
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        animationView.loopAnimation = true
        animationView.animationSpeed = 0.5
        view.addSubview(animationView)

        animationView.play()
    }}
```

Comment: Your code should work take a look at this [demo](https://github.com/appcoda/LottieDemo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove `if let` from your code. To use if let you must have an `Optional` variable.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("view loaded")

     animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "pop_heart") 
     animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)
     animationView.center = self.view.center
     animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
     animationView.loopAnimation = true
     animationView.animationSpeed = 0.5
     view.addSubview(animationView)
     animationView.play()
}
```

or if you want to use `if let` you can use if like this.

```
if let value = someMethodWhichReturnsAny as? String {
    //In above like there is a method which returns a string but in the form of type `Any` so I downcast it to String with optional and remove the nil case with if let
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//test

```
         let backgroundAnimation: LOTAnimationView = {
                let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "10173-success-lumina")
             animationView.loopAnimation = true
                animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                return animationView
            }()

         backgroundAnimation.frame = view.frame
         view.addSubview(backgroundAnimation)
         view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundAnimation)
         backgroundAnimation.play()

     }
```